# ¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre un Middleware y un Proxy?

Tags: nodejs, proxy, middleware

He estado investigando un poco y realmente aún no me queda claro cuál es la diferencia entre estos dos conceptos, puesto que ambos hacen de intermediario entre dos partes (cliente-servidor o dos aplicaciones). ¿El middleware sirve principalmente para filtrar las peticiones y el proxy solo es para ocultar tu identidad real a la otra parte y proporcionar seguridad? No me acaba de quedar claro.

Comment: Dependiendo del grado de configuración de un proxy, cuando este recibe una petición transfoma los valores del request (generalmente los datos con los que un equipo puede ser identificado en la red). Al final es un termediario entre el servidor y el cliente. La idea de este último es que no se conecte directamente. El middleware sería la lógica que responde a la petición echa por el cliente. (El cliente directo ó el proxy en mediación de este)

Comment: El proxy tiene muchas funciones, puedes ver algo más detallado aquí: https://www.mcafee.com/blogs/es-es/privacy-identity-protection/que-es-un-proxy/#:~:text=Un%20servidor%20proxy%20es%20una,a%20Internet%20de%20manera%20indirecta.